# Game-Logic Problems

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

I've got a character set up with a basic static animation, walk animation, and a run animation. I've got keyboard sensors set up for the walk and run, and they are linked into AND controllers and ACTION actuators. The static I've setup through an ALWAYS sensor, AND controller and an ACTION actuator. Blender freezes when I try to run. I've tried changing the priorities and turning on "", but nothing seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: Do you only have two ACTION-actuators?
What do you mean with freezes? doesn't it anything or is the static-animation played?

Comment: the static animation is always running, and when I press W it runs the walk animation just fine, but as soon as I press forward and shift to activate the run animation my character freezes in mid air, and stays that way until I jump out of 'play' mode.

Answer (score 3):

To find an answer I recreated a 'working' example:

Three different Animations called Static, Walk and Run

1. The Always-sensor is connected with the static-action. This animation will be played always unless an other animations gets played with a higher priority (lower number)
2. The Walk-sensor is connected with the and-controller called 'Walk' and the and-controller called 'Run'. Because this sensor is the only one, that is connected to the "walk"-controller, this controller will activate the connected actuators if the Walk-sensor gets activated. This will trigger the walk-action whose priority is higher than this from the static-action. This will 'override' the static-animation
3. The Run-sensor is connected to the and-controller called 'Run'. Because this is an and-controller, this will trigger the connected actuators if ALL connected sensors are triggered. In this case when the Keys [W] and [Left Shift] are pressed TOGETHER. This will then activate the run-action which has a higher priority than the static-action and the walk-action.

Note:

The Action-Mode 'Loop Stop' is chosen because this will loop the animation, but it will not finish the animation, if interrupted.

I made a screenshot of the node-map:
[image]

I hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is the exact setup I had, changed the priorities, but still doing the same thing. I am running version 2.7.7. Could it possibly a BGE update that I am just unaware of? Keeping in mind I'm don't have a particularly vast knowledge of Blender :/

Comment: Ok, so Ihad a better look at your setup and mine did have a few differences, however now that mine IS setup like yours, the animation no longer freezes, but when I activate the RUN animation it just stays on on frame, and once I release LShift it goes back to walk, or static

Comment: OH my soul, I did not have an 'end frame' for the run animation! Nevertheless I am grateful for the help guys! people like you make Blender great :)

Comment: Great to hear, that it worked and I could help somehow :)